# Sampling covergroup of parameter array - systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, verification

Let's say I have an array of parameters I want to use in a covergroup.
In order to interate over all the parameters in the array I tried to use a for loop in this manner:

```
array [5];
covergroup param;
 coefficient: coverpoint array[i]{
 bin low = {0:50};
 bins high = {51:100};
 }

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 param = new(i);

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 param.sample(i);
```

I'm not really sure how to solve this rather than creating a coverpoint for every cell in the array, but that's just messy and wrong.

Comment: You can only cover integral values, no arrays or such.

Comment: Try changing `covergroup param;` to `covergroup param(int i);`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the input argument to the covergroup.

```
int array [5];

covergroup param (ref int a);
 coefficient: coverpoint a{
 bin low = {0:50};
 bins high = {51:100};
 }
endgroup

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 param = new(array[i]);

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 param.sample();
```